# how to put value in value attribute of option

Tags: jquery

I have a value of a variable x and wants to select the correct option of a     select tag. I am doing this but didn't getting answer and getting empty []

```
var x = 2
var c = $('#data6 option[value=x]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to concatenate the variable `x` with the selector string... `$('#data6 option[value="' + x + '"]')`

Answer (score 0):

The value x is an integer and you are placing an integer in middle of a string.  Try something like this:

```
var c = $('#data6 option[value=' + x.toString() + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```